# HTML image and div resize

Tags: html

```
.d1 {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="d1">
    <img src="http://www.aliceseelywholesale.net/wp-content/uploads/ADB101-DAISY-CUTOUT-NARROW-LINK-BRACELET-300x100.jpg">
</div>
```

I use the above simple code to display an `image` in the middle a `div`. Code works good however when I resize the window below the width of the image, the border/div doesn't cover the image... Is there a way to fix this? Ty

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a backgound image for your `<div>` I suggest you set the image as a `background-image` for your div, and remove your `<img>` element.

This will save you from using an addition element and also fix your problem:

```css
.d1 {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(http://www.aliceseelywholesale.net/wp-content/uploads/ADB101-DAISY-CUTOUT-NARROW-LINK-BRACELET-300x100.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Indeed that worked better but the image isn't centered this time... Do you maybe know how to solve this last one?

Comment: Add `background-size:cover;`

Answer (score 4):

```
.d1 {
   background-color: red;
} 
.img{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Treat the Image as a block content not as inline-element.

I hope this helps.